# Server response == 0 interpreted as Boolean YES

Tags: objective-c, json, boolean

I'm getting a server response in a JSON object that has a value of `0`. I want to interpret this as `FALSE` or `NO`, but I am getting the opposite result. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
NSString *text=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:d.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", text);
self.response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:d.receivedData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [[self.response valueForKey:@"message"] valueForKey:@"app_version_status"]);
int temp = (int)[[self.response valueForKey:@"message"] valueForKey:@"app_version_status"];
NSLog(@"%d", temp);
NSLog(temp ? @"yes" : @"no");
```

And this is my console output:

```
2014-05-16 14:18:35.819 MyApp[4410:60b] {"result":"success","message":{"app_version_status":0}}
2014-05-16 14:18:35.847 MyApp[4410:60b] 0
2014-05-16 14:18:35.847 MyApp[4410:60b] 3  //<-- What???
2014-05-16 14:18:35.847 MyApp[4410:60b] yes
```

Comment: Any non-0 number is "true" in a conditional in C (and Objective-C), so that part can be discarded. Then just focus on the cast - what *is* the value before the cast?

Comment: But the server response is '0'. That makes it zero, right?

Comment: If the server response is the character "0" that is not zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the cast to int, you'll get an error telling you exactly what's wrong — you're getting an *object*, not an int. In this case, it's probably an NSNumber. If you want an int, ask for its `intValue`.

In general, it's good to be very conservative about casting. If you're getting a type error, don't use a cast to make it go away unless you're 100% certain it's spurious. If there was a real error, it will probably still be there with the cast, but now you've told the compiler you don't want to hear about it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! (I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to).

Comment: "[I]t's probably an NSNumber." Given that it's deserialized from JSON, wouldn't it be an `NSString`? Anyway, excellent advice on avoiding the misuse of casts. +1 for that alone. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`self.response` is actually an `NSNumber` object. It is not the scalar value of `0`, it is an object with an internal property that evaluates to `0`.

By typecasting the reference to an object (a pointer so to say) to int you actually get the value of the pointer (of which I am a bit surprised that it is 'only' 3) and not the value of any property of the object.

(From a C perspective, and obj-c is an extenstion to C, an object is represented in memory as any C struct is.)

Then you go forward with your pointer and try to evaluate it as a `boolean`. Any value different from `0`, and `3` is different from `0`, will evaluate to `TRUE`. Only 0 evaluates to FALSE.

Try using

```
NSNumber myIntNumber = self.response;
NSLog (@"%@", myIntNumber), 
NSLog (@"%d", [myIntNumber intValue]);
NSLog (@"%d", [myIntNumber booleanValue]);
NSLog (@"%d", [myIntNumber booleanValue] ? @"yes" : @"no");
```

... and you will understand.

Comment: It's 3 because Objective-C uses tagged pointers nowadays. IIRC a 1 in the low-order bit indicates that it's tagged, a 1 in the next bit indicates that it's a number, and the rest of the bits are 0 because the number is 0, so you get the bit pattern `0000…0011`, which looks like the integer 3. (The tags may work slightly differently than I remember, but the general idea is something like that.)

Comment: @Chuck, interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Taking @Chuck's comment into account, that means that self.response is null and not an NSNumber carrying the value of 0. But I don't see why.

Comment: It's not NULL. AFAIK it's the tagged pointer value representing the number 0, the same as you'd get from `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]`. NULL is still all zeroes.